# Does a level set of a harmonic function have an analytic parametrisation?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, manifolds, harmonic-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set. Suppose $f(x,y)$ is a harmonic function on $U$. If $\nabla f=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in U$, then the zero set of $f$ is a real analytic curve by the Regular Value Theorem. Suppose the curve is connected and closed. I want to know whether I can express the curve as $t\mapsto(x(t),y(t))$, where $x(t)$, $y(t)$ are real analytic.

Comment: [Definition: Analytic Curve](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_curve): "A curve with an analytic parametrization." Since the domain of a curve is an interval in the real numbers, and the coordinates of the curve all have codomain $\Bbb R$, this means "Real".

Comment: If we use Regular Value Theorem,  we only have this curve as a real analytic manifold. I want to know if this manifold has an analytic parametrization.

Comment: @zeng Out of curiosity, do you know whether or not this curve is always closed? If so why?